# How to remove lines from string without allocating memory for new strings?

Tags: erlang, elixir

I want to remove some lines from a large text file, but I want to do this without allocating more memory than is required for holding the original string. So far, I can only manage the following:

```
s
|> StringIO.open()
|> then(fn {:ok, device} ->
  IO.binstream(device, :line)
end)
|> Stream.reject(&Regex.match?(~r{<date_of_creation>.*</date_of_creation>\n}, &1))
|> Enum.join()
```

But this ends up doubling the memory required for the original string, because of the join at the end. Is there a better way to do this with just Elixir/Erlang?

Comment: Looks like XML, is it?

Comment: Yes, it is XML.

Comment: This code has many issues besides allocating memory: it uses `bin` mode reading text file, it’d ignore multiline, weird-formed and all other kinds of tags, etc. Parse XML with XML-handling library in the first place. Regarding the memory, it depends on what would you want to do with the string, but this code does not double anything, it streams chunks and then constructs a single binary.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin You're making a ton of assumptions about what I'm doing with this. I don't need to parse this xml, so I will not be doing any of that. You're right of course that this code streams the chunks and constructs a single binary. But isn't that how it double the memory? As now there is the original string represented by `s` in addition to the string produced by the join.

Comment: I have not made a single assumption, on contrary, I explicitly stated “it depends on what would you want to do with the string.” If you have a string upfront and you need a string back, there is no way of “modifying it inplace” due to immutability of the language. OTOH, you might start with converting the string to charlist and then dealing with lists, with the unpredictable result (depending on what would you do with it,) which would require benchmarks. In any case, doubling the memory is not an issue in 99% of cases, and if it is, you should not have it in memory upfront in the first place.

Comment: Does the large text file have reasonable line breaks? If so you could process a line at a time and then the doubling of line memory wouldn't be a factor.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin You have made assumptions, and I don't care to explain them to you, as they're irrelevant to the question. Please refrain from distracting any further from the question. If the answer is that you cannot modify a string in place, then that will suffice, assuming you are not mistaken.

Comment: Depending on what you want to do with the result, there might be a way to considerably reduce the memory usage by avoiding using `Enum.join/1` and replacing `Stream.reject/2` by `Enum.reject/2`. This would give you an [IO list](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/IO.html#module-io-data) which might be used directly in many cases.

Comment: @sabiwara This is the answer I was looking for. Thank you for your constructive comment, but it should have been submitted as an answer.

Comment: Will do! It really depended on the use case so I submitted as a question first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you want to do with the result, a way to considerably reduce the memory usage is to avoid build the string in the first place and use [`IO data`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/IO.html#module-io-data).

In your example, this could be achieved by removing the call to `Enum.join/1` and replace `Stream.reject/2` by `Enum.reject/2`:

```elixir
|> Enum.reject(&Regex.match?(~r{<date_of_creation>.*</date_of_creation>\n}, &1))
```

This will return an IO list which can be used directly for I/O, and you might not need the string at all. This is how Phoenix is able to render templates/JSON efficiently: avoiding expensive string concatenation in the first place.

Assuming you had to join with a separator (`Enum.join/2`), [`Enum.intersperse/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#intersperse/2) could be used to build an IO list.